# Activity Duration in Hours extension NOT working for CiviCase

Tags: extension, civicase, activities

Currently using CiviCRM Version 5.31 (Wordpress Version 5.5.3)

Installed the extension to change Activities Duration from Minutes to Hours

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/activityhours

The extension works for Contact Activities but not Case Activities.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what needs to be done to make the changes in Case Activities ?

===========================================================================

Hi Demerit, thank you for the prompt response.

I changed the lines in both activityhours.php and activityhours.js but the duration for case activities are still in 'minutes'.

Please advise

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing [this line](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/activityhours/-/blob/a459af5c4d5128a1f510a0eaabdd2e565909523b/activityhours.php#L141) in activityhours.php from:

`if ($formName == 'CRM_Activity_Form_Activity' && !CRM_Utils_Request::retrieveValue('snippet', 'String')) {`

to

`if (($formName == 'CRM_Activity_Form_Activity' || $formName == 'CRM_Case_Form_Activity') && !CRM_Utils_Request::retrieveValue('snippet', 'String')) {`

You'd probably also have to add some selectors in the .js file, e.g. whereever it says `.crm-activity-form-block-duration` also add `.crm-case-activity-form-block-duration`

You could post a feature request at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/activityhours/-/issues, but if you're able to also post a merge request with some tested code changes that would be best.

Comment: Hi Demerit, thank you for the prompt response. I have changed the lines based on your advice but the duration is still in minutes (Please see above). Please

Comment: I was giving general instructions but you're going to have to investigate further and find the right things to add. The javascript I mentioned is just for viewing not editing but note you would need to add a selector as an additional target not insert the class into the existing target. For editing just the line in activityhours.php should work but note that on a New Case it's a different form so you would need to make additional adjustments specific to Open Case. It will take some trial and error.

Comment: My apologies: not being a coder & with English being a second language. I hope for a more layman explanation/ instructions

Comment: No need to apologize it's just to add a feature like this and work out the details and test it etc someone will have to put in some time and effort.